# In Stanford Topic Modeling Toolkit (TMT), what does the number against a topic mean (in the output file "summary.txt")?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, lda, topic-modeling

A typical snippet from Stanford TMT's 'summary.txt' file is as follows:

```
Topic00   37.47500834475079
    term1 11.163093014855274
    term2 2.8478206435760547
    term3 1.905685547333616
    term4 1.8341840331688735
```

So far, the only information I have been able to get regarding the numbers is this (from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4):

`[Snapshot]/summary.txt Human readable summary of the topic model, with top-20 terms per topic and how many words instances of each have occurred.`

But what does the number against the topic mean? (In this example, `Topic00   37.47500834475079`)

Comment: i think you need to specify the configurations you used to get those numbers to get an authoritative answer. Normally it's the generative weights that was assigned and reassigned upon the iteration when during some sort of di/convergence. good question, what exactly is the number?

Comment: @chtnonic-project: did you ever figure this out? I'm asking myself the same question.

Comment: Sadly, no. If I do find out the answer, I'll certainly provide it here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in the source code it is "how many times each topic is seem overall"

Comment: It need not be an integer. I am quite sure the values are something similar to a probability distribution of the topics over all the documents. But, since the values aren't in the `[0,1]` range, it's not a prob. distribution ... the documentation doesn't say anything more, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndyHayden, I have the same comment. Did you figure this out?

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese I'm afraid I've no idea.

Answer (score 0):

For example your output have 30 topics. Each topic shows its top words, and the relative weight of these words per topic

Comment: what do you mean by "relative weights"? Relative to what?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the value is the distribution in the topic. It can also express the importance in the topic. You can see the number after Topic 00, which is the sum of the weights of all terms. You can also check the topic-term-distributions.csv. You will see the sum of each row is equal to the number after "Topic **".